# Best way to include location services in an api

Tags: java, android

Looking into writing an API to simplify access to a set of REST services.  These services require a user location to be made successfully.

I am currently using the `LocationManager` to accomplish this, but I am aware of the `FusedLocationApi` offered by the Google Play Services.  The biggest issue I run into is the Google Play Services api isn't really good for packaging into my API, but the `LocationManager` seems to fit better.

Is there a good way to use the `FusedLocationApi` in a distributable package nicely without having to jump through all the hoops that is connecting to the play services in order to get to the location api for actually use it?

Comment: `jump through all the hoops` can you be more specific?

Comment: I don't want my api to have to implement the requirements to connect the client and handle the resolution of issues with the play services.  Seems awkward as well cause a consumer to implement this if they don't even want to use any of the other play services as well.

Comment: you have to connect to Google Play Services via API key in order to access API calls (in this case you want location based API calls). There is no way you could leverage your own API to make this easier without every user then just using your library as proxy to get to Google Maps API (in effect also using your API key). And from a scalability stand point if you have lots of users using your API, then it gets really expensive quick. People would essentially use your API as a free means to using Google Maps API

Comment: @LucasCrawford Accessing the `FusedLocationApi` doesn't require an API Key.  From what I'm aware of, it uses native libraries and **fuses** them together to create the `FusedLocationApi`.  I'm not wanting to use maps, just get rough GPS coordinates for the user's device.

Comment: I don't quite understand. it seems it would be a good thing to put in a library, something to access more easily to the fused location api by masking the complexity of obtaining the client and handling the error cases. why wouldn't you want to put that in the package you are writing?

Comment: @njzk2 Because the `GoogleApiClient` is used to connect more that just location services.  If they want more I would have to expose it, which doesn't make sense.  Further more, my api isn't concerned with UI.  Now I have to concern myself with a way to push messages to the user, very invasive, for one reason or another, play services not installed, version not update-to-date, etc...  Location services are native to the device and using the `GoogleApiClient` doesn't seem like a good fit for a packaged library.